# Jenkins + RTC : How to add new text field to jenkins UI if my class is extending RtcExtensionProvider?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, rational-team-concert

I am to devlopting one jenkins plugin by extending RtcExtensionProvider and its entry method is getComponentLoadRules (below is the code sample).i want to add a custom text feild on jenkins UI, for that i have to extens Builder plugin which is not possible because i already extends my class with RtcExtensionProvider.if i will create a new class XYZ extends Builder then also i am not able to call getComponentLoadRules method of class JenkinsLoad.
Is there any way to add custom fild on jenkins ui which below code possiblity?

`@Extension

public class JenkinsLoad extends RtcExtensionProvider implements Serializable {

@Override

public Map getComponentLoadRules(String workspaceUUID, String workspaceName, String buildResultUUID,Map componentInfo, String repoURL, String userId, String password, PrintStream logger)throws IOException, KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CloneNotSupportedException {

// rest code
      }
      }`